# Eclipse EPF RichText Editor - sensitive paste of MS Word text

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ms-word, eclipse-rcp, copy-paste, rich-text-editor

I have got a Java application that uses the EPF RichTextEditor component/plugin. Everything works quite well. The problems appear if a user pastes some text that has originally been copied from an MS Word document. Pasting this text leads to a mess in the HTML source and also in the preview.

Of course I could write some methods that clean up the text afterwards. But I have seen online editors that come with a button like "paste from word". My question is, does there exist something similar for the EPF RichTextEditor?